# How to check if a signal does not change using Immediate Assertions in SystemVerilog Assertions

Tags: system-verilog, system-verilog-assertions

I'm new to SystemVerilog Assertions and I know that I can check if a signal doesn't change between clock ticks using Concurrent Assertions:

```
assert property (@(posedge clk) enable == 0 |=> $stable(data));
```

But how would I do so continuously using Immediate Assertions? This is an example that I found online but I'm not sure if it's what I need and how it works:

```
assign not_a = !a;
always_comb begin : b1
    a1: assert (not_a != a);
    a2: assert #0 (not_a!= a); // Should pass once values have settled
end
```

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking for does not make any sense. If it a signal never can change, then it must be a constant. With the example you show, `a1` might fail - there is a race condition between `a` and `not_a`. `a2` is deferred assertion - it takes care of the race and will never fail. But the problem with both these assertions is that if `a` changes at some time, `a2` never fails and you may are may not see a failure with `a1`

Comment: Thank you for your comment. I think I didn't word my question properly, All I'm looking for is to use Immediate Assertions to check if a signal is stable, since I don't have a clock.

Comment: Without any reference, what is your definition of _stable_?

Comment: The signal does not change when the assertion is running.

Comment: So without any reference, when should the assertion start running, and when should it stop? My definition of **stable**  means check for no change during some period or time window. You can't use the signal itself as a reference because it is indeed stable between its changes.

Comment: The signal A needs to stay the same when ever an other signal, B, is high. Sorry for all the confusion.